# what's wrong with my C# codes in INSERT command with Parameter?

Tags: c#

my friends , what's wrong with these codes that it appear "Input string was not in a correct format." Error ?????????

it appears in lines witch start with *
who can help me?

```
 try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO fact_info(fact_id, druge,price,amount,total,selldate) VALUES (@C1, @C2, @C3, @C4, @C5 ,@C6)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C1", SqlDbType.Int ));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C2", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C3", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C4", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C5", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C6", SqlDbType.NVarChar ));
                    con.Open();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNewRow)
                        {
                            *****cmd.Parameters["@C1"].Value =Convert .ToInt32 (  label3.Text.Trim());
                            cmd.Parameters["@C2"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString ();*****
                            cmd.Parameters["@C3"].Value =Convert .ToInt32 ( row.Cells[2].Value.ToString ());
                            cmd.Parameters["@C4"].Value =Convert .ToInt32 ( row.Cells[3].Value.ToString ());
                            cmd.Parameters["@C5"].Value =Convert .ToInt32 ( row.Cells[4].Value.ToString ());
                            cmd.Parameters["@C6"].Value = label5.Text.Trim();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done! ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: your `label3.Text` is not an `integer` representation. It can't be parsed into an integer.

Comment: When you've sorted that passing dates as strings is not a brill idea either. SellDate is a date/datetime isn't it?

Comment: Also, why are you using a loop?  There's only one query being executed, so it's only ever going to `INSERT` the last row in the table.

Comment: Label3.text has my FactID and I wanna convert it to Int

Comment: in My SQL table , i designed the Selldate as in NVarchar

Comment: Well seeing as it's a date. Undesign as NVarchar, and design it as a date. That's just a good way of crashing when someone puts 30th February in there. Or they have their system configured to american and then in your european system it says 2/28/2013 is not a date.

Answer (score 3):

Which line throws the error?  If I were to guess, it's likely that the error is happening here:

```
Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text.Trim())
```

What is the runtime value of `label3.Text`?  If it's not a numeric (integer, specifically) value, then `Convert.ToInt32` is going to throw an exception because it can't be converted to an `int`.  You might want to add some run-time checking on the value:

```
var factID = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(label3.Text, out factID))
{
    // The label doesn't have an integer.
    // Display an error to the user, perhaps?
    // Either way, don't continue because there will be an error.
}
```

If the label has an integer, `factID` will be that integer.  If it doesn't, you can handle the error condition here.

Comment: yes, that's it ! my table field type is "Int" and i converted the amount of Label3.text into Int32 . isn't true???

Comment: @Elena what is the value of `Label3.Text`? if the value is not a number (let's say it says `"Foo"` instead of something like `"12"` then what number would it convert `"Foo"` in to?)

Comment: @Elena: It's true that you'd need to use an integer value to insert into an integer column in the database.  The problem isn't with the database, it's with the value.  If `Convert.ToInt32()` is throwing the error then clearly `label3.Text` isn't an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

The value in `label3.Text` is not a valid integer and so `Convert.ToInt32` can't parse it into an int thus throws the error instead. Either handle the exception in a `Try...Catch` block or use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead.